# How to refresh particular drop down only in parent page after closing popup

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have one drop down in my parent page which selects agencies and one add button next to it to add new agency. This button opens the popup window. when I add new agency the drop down in parent page should only be refreshed. But all solutions are giving me  way to refresh the whole parent page which I do not want.
How to refresh drop down only in parent page.

Comment: AJAX will allow you to get data from the server and "refresh" part of a page.

Comment: Really thankful for this help. can u plz explain with some example

Comment: Here you go: https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_ajax_php.asp  Research is your friend.  There are many others to choose from.

Answer (score 0):

You may consider using Angular, Vue.js or React to get responsive front-end like this.
Another way is using JS to refresh the DOM of the drop down over time (worst than the first alternative)

Answer (score 0):

Finally got the way to resolve this issue very efficiently. Here is my code

This code is for the popup window in which I am adding new edition type. In this popup I am calling the reload of that particular drop down which will get refreshed after adding new edition type.

script in popup:

```
window.onunload = refreshParent;
function refreshParent() {
   // window.opener.location.reload();
    window.top.close();
}

window.onbeforeunload = function(e) {
window.opener.trial1();
window.top.close();
```

};

And now this is the code in parent window.
script in parent page:

```
                        function trial1(){

                        $( "#abc" ).load( "billGeneration.php #abc select" );

                        }
                        /*script ends here*/


                         <input type="button"  name="trial3" id="trial3" value="btn" onClick="trial1()">

                        <div class="row">
                        <div class="col col-md-3">
                         <span style="color:#000066;">Select Edition :</span>
                        </div>

                        <div id="abc" class="col-12 col-md-7" style="text-align:left;">
                        <select name="edition" id="edition" class="form-control"   onchange="editiondata(this)">
                                                     <option value="0" >Please select</option>
                                                     <!--code for fetching customer names in dropdown-->
                                                     <?php

                                                        $query1 = "SELECT edition_name FROM tb_edition";
                                                                             $result1 = mysql_query($query1, $con) or die(mysql_error($con));
                                                        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result1)){
                                                            //$edition = $row["edition_name"];
                                                        ?>
                                                     <option id="opt" data-edition_value="<?php if(isset($row["edition_name"])) echo $row["edition_name"];?>" value="<?php if(isset($row["edition_name"])) echo $row["edition_name"];?>"><?php if(isset($row["edition_name"])) echo $row["edition_name"];?></option>
                                                     <?php
                                                    }
                                                        ?>
                                                     <!--****************************************************-->
                                                  </select>
                        </div>
```

This will refresh the drop down only without refreshing whole parent page.